# Thermostat resetting to wrong temperature

Tags: thermostat, furnace

I have an Emerson programmable thermostat (seems to be similar to https://climate.emerson.com/documents/blue-universal-thermostat-istruction-sheet-en-4211880.pdf).   I went through and programmed it several years ago and haven't touched the programming since.

Recently the thermostat has been changing the set point.  I'll look at the unit and instead of the current set being 67 or 70 or whatever, it'll be 62 (always 62).   Further, it has brought up "resume program" as an option, so it acts as if I've done a temporary override.   If use the resume, it will go back to the correct set point, but only for a few minutes (maybe 10-15 minutes or so?  I've not actually caught it in the act)

If I engage "hold", it will stay at the hold point.

I pulled the unit and found one of the batteries was leaking.  I replaced them, but no change (and it didn't seem like a big problem ; the board sits mostly above the batteries, so didn't get covered with gunk).  The unit is wired so the batteries should only be used during a power failure.

I don't see any alerts, but this seems like such a strange failure mode.  It's obviously not the program, since I can resume the program and the setpoint will be temporarily correct.  But something is overriding.  Is there any chance this is an indication of a furnace problem, or more likely something with the thermostat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmph.  I believe it was in fact the batteries.

I finally was able to "catch it" when it lost the setpoint.   All of sudden, the battery symbol appeared, started flashing, setpoint changed, and a charge warning of some sort appeared.  Then a few seconds later, those symbols go away, so there's no later indication that the batteries were the problem.

Reexamined the battery compartment and although the springs looked good (which is where the battery appeared to be leaking), the metal contactor/lid had gunk that I had missed earlier.  I scraped it with a penny for a few seconds and put it back together.  It's been at temp for an hour now.

Comment: something is wrong. `Thermostat can be powered by system AC power or Battery`. check if you get the 24 volt between R and C..Take the batteries out, it should be still working if it gets 24 V power

Comment: Presumably true.  I didn't test that before cleaning the contacts better.  But yes, its still working if I pull the batteries now.

Comment: Spoke too soon.  I left the batteries out overnight to test.  This morning, the unit was back on 62.  So seems like it doesn't enjoy running without the batteries.

Comment: You should just replace the whole thing. It's a generic basic programmable thermostat, and it will cost you far more money and grief if it completely fails while you're on vacation and causes your pipes to burst.

Comment: Not an issue here.  No freezing, and the pipes here aren't protected by the inside furnace anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I was going after the 24 Volt supply consistency.

Your battery got drained because the 24 Volt was not there and the thermostat was running on battery.

You must check with multimeter that you have 24 Volt (AC) on the thermostat between the R and C.

If all is correct, double check your thermostat settings. The 62 F setting must come from the thermostat programing.

I have Nest that knows when I am not at home (using my cell phone) and lowers the temperature.

Comment: The wired power seems to be working.  When the unit is detached and the batteries are pulled, the display shuts off after about 2 minutes.   It comes back on when reattached.  I had it running overnight with batteries removed.  Setpoint goes off, but otherwise functions okay.

Comment: Good to know, so it is not the power problem. It should not need battery then.

Comment: It must be in the setting or broken thermostat. Check your settings for temperature change programed. I have Nest that knows when I am not at home (using my cell phone) and lowers the temperature. Does yours do that ? The 62 F is pretty consistent indicating it is programed to do so.

Comment: looks like it does need battery.  When the batteries are out, setpoint goes to 62 after a period of time.  But with the batteries in, it works fine.

The manual says with "less than 2 months of battery life remain", the setpoint will move 10 degrees off.  My setpoint isn't 72, so this isn't correct.  But perhaps it's similar.  Odd is that it wasn't (at least not consistently) showing any battery alerts.

No, this one doesn't have any sort of occupancy sensors.